# MPR makedeb/mist is not working for the python3-krfzf-py-git 0.0.4.r1.e403493-2 package: unrecognized argument: --prefix=/usr

Tags: python, ubuntu, deb

I am trying to get mov-cli to work, and one of its dependencies is python3-krfzf-py. The error I get using `makedeb` is:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 satisfy:command-line : Depends: python3-krfzf-py but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
[!] Failed to install missing dependencies.
```

I then tried `mist install mov-cli` and got the following:

```
The following packages will be installed:
  mpr/python3-krfzf-py-git mpr/mov-cli

Review:
- 2 to install
- 0 to remove
- 0 to upgrade
- 0 to downgrade

Would you like to continue? [Y/n] y

Info: Making sure Git repository for 'python3-krfzf-py-git' is up to date...
Info: Cloning 'mov-cli' Git repository from the MPR...

Question: Review files for 'python3-krfzf-py-git'? [Y/n] n

Question: Review files for 'mov-cli'? [Y/n] n
Info: Running makedeb for 'python3-krfzf-py-git'...
[#] Making package: python3-krfzf-py-git 0.0.6.r1.54e41d6-1 (Tue Feb 20 01:18:58 2024)
[#] Checking for missing dependencies...
[#] Loading extensions...
[#] Retrieving sources...
  [->] Updating fzf.py git repo...
Fetching origin
[#] Validating source files with b2sums...
    fzf.py ... Skipped
[#] Extracting sources...
  [->] Creating working copy of fzf.py git repo...
[#] Starting pkgver()...
[#] Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
[#] Starting build()...
* Getting dependencies for wheel...
* Building wheel...
Successfully built krfzf.py-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl
[#] Entering fakeroot environment...
[#] Starting package()...
usage: python -m installer [-h] [--destdir path] [--compile-bytecode level] [--no-compile-bytecode] wheel
python -m installer: error: unrecognized arguments: --prefix=/usr
[! package()] A failure occurred in package().
    Aborting...
Err: Failed to run makedeb.
```

I originally also had an issue with pycryptodome-fix, but I was able to resolve that one. This one seems to be a problem with the `--prefix='/usr'` line within the PKGBUILD for python3-krfzf-py. I tried installing just python3-krfzf-py by itself (instead of through mist on mov-cli) but I get the same issue.

```
[#] Starting package()...
usage: python -m installer [-h] [--destdir path] [--compile-bytecode level] [--no-compile-bytecode] wheel
python -m installer: error: unrecognized arguments: --prefix=/usr
[! package()] A failure occurred in package().
    Aborting...
```

I felt like I was running out of options, so I even tried to remove the `--prefix="/usr"` prefix inside the PKGBUILD file, but that led to further issues. Any ideas?

Sorry, I'm not used to Stack Overflow, so I'm not entirely sure how this box differs from the previous section. But a summary of what I did is:

1. Try `makedeb -si` in mov-cli clone. This resulted in errors for 2 dependencies, `python3-pycryptodome-fix` and `python3-krfzf-py-git`
2. I then ran `makedeb` without the `-si` iption in order to see all dependencies, and installed them all manually. This worked for most of them, but the two listed previous still had issues.
3. I looked up pycryptodome-fix and found it on MPR. I then used a `makedeb` on a clone of that, and it worked.
4. Assuming that this was the solution to my problem, I did the same for python3-krfzf-py-git, but I will list it in more detail since it is not working.
5. I ran `git clone https://mpr.makedeb.org/python3-krfzf-py-git.git` to clone it
6. I cd'ed into the folder
7. I ran `makedeb -si` and got the errors detailed previously
8. I ran `makedeb` to see if any dependencies were the problem. They were not.
9. I installed mist, and tried to use `mist install mov-cli` and `mist install python3-krfzf-py-git`. Both led to the same error detailed above
10. I opened PKGBUILD in notepad and removed the `--prefix="/usr"` from the `python3 -m` install command. This led to far more errors, so I reverted.

It should be noted that I deleted and recloned multiple times during this (at least 10-15 times), so there are no problems with the clone.

Comment: Ok, I was able to resolve the current problem (I think), by editing the PKGBUILD for mov-cli to not depend on python3-krfzf-py. Obviously, this is not a great solution, and I'm not sure if it hurts any functionality, so I am leaving the question open for now.

Comment: This seems to require some rather specialized knowledge. What is `mist` and how does it relate to creating Debian packages?